# ('Nmap not found', <class 'nmap.nmap.PortScannerError'>)

Tags: python

Where is the problem?

```
import nmap
```

I installed nmap and python, and when I use `import nmap` there is no any problem. But when use:

```
nmap.PortScanner()
```

this error is thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    nmap.PortScanner()
  File "./nmap/nmap.py", line 153, in __init__
    raise PortScannerError('nmap program was not found in path. PATH is:{0}'.format(os.getenv('PATH')))
nmap.nmap.PortScannerError: 'nmap program was not found in path. PATH is : /usr/lib    /lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:    /usr/local/games'"
```

Comment: Where is `nmap` installed then? The error message tells you where the `nmap` module tried to find it.

Comment: you had installed `nmap` via pip?

Comment: for installing in download nmap from [link](http://xael.org/norman/python/python-nmap/) and install by consol:                      tar xvzf python-nmap-0.2.6.tar.gz
cd python-nmap-0.2.6
python setup.py install . i copy python-nmap-0.2.7 in my home then installed it.

Comment: You do have nmap installed as well? python-nmap is the Python module which relies on nmap also being installed. Try "nmap -V" from unix command line.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`python-nmap` seems to depend on `nmap`, which is the binary that does the actual network scanning and auditing.

You can check in a terminal if nmap is in your `$PATH` with the following command:

```
 which nmap
```

#### Debian-like

You can install nmap in debian-like distros with:

```
apt-get install nmap
```

#### Arch linux:

```
pacman -Sy nmap
```

#### Already installed `nmap`

If you're sure the `nmap` binary is installed, but you think it is not in your `$PATH`, you might have to add the directory where nmap is installed to your `$PATH`.

To do that, edit the `.bashrc` file in your user's directory, or `/etc/bashrc` (which will change for all users) and add the following:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/nmap/bin"
```

but changing `/usr/local/nmap/bin` for the directory where the nmap binary is installed.
After changing the file, be sure to open a new shell session, or type `exec bash` to refresh it.

You also have to make sure, that it has execute permission (`chmod +x <file>`).

When you execute:

```
nmap --version
```

You should see something like this:

```
Nmap version 6.46 ( http://nmap.org )
Platform: i686-pc-linux-gnu
Compiled with: liblua-5.2.3 openssl-1.0.1g libpcre-8.34 libpcap-1.5.3 nmap-libdnet-1.12 ipv6
Compiled without:
Available nsock engines: epoll poll select
```

If you do, `nmap` is installed and in your `$PATH`.

Comment: I am not able to fix the steps given. What I am doing is I am running my script on cloud. I have installed nmap there which shows the path of the executable nmap - /usr/bin/nmap. Also I have added it to my PATH variable. But I am getting the error as:
 raise PortScannerError('nmap program was not found in path')

Comment: Are you sure that, if you open a new shell, that shell will have the nmap binary in the $PATH?

Comment: Yes please wait for some time and I will soon give a link to the video of my shell

Answer (score 15):

**For Windows users:**

I would suggest first closing all terminals and IDLE or any other window you currently have opened when trying to run your script.

Next, open a command line and type

```
pip uninstall python-nmap
```

If you are unsure if Nmap binaries are installed on your current system, do a simple search for

```
nmap
```

from your start menu. If it is installed, continue to the next step, if not, go to [Nmap's official download page](https://nmap.org/download.html)

Download the windows self install and run it. Record the directory it is being installed to.

Go to that directory. For me it was

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap`

Open your system's environment variables editor usually found in

```
My PC > System Information > Advance settings > Environment Variables
```

Or right click

> My PC or My Computer or whatever yours is called and select properties then advance settings then Environment Variables at the bottom of the Advanced tab

select `Path` for both `You` and the `System`

press `Edit` and enter the `full path to your Nmap director`

eg `;C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap\`

Press ok and exit the editor.

Now go back to your command line and enter: `pip install python-nmap`
Allow it to install and then restart your `ide` and test your code again.

Comment: ***choco install python***, ***choco install nmap*** and ***pip install python-nmap***

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem. Just type in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install nmap
```

and problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows:
I found this helpful:

```
choco install nmap
```

You must run this under an elevated command if possibly Powershell
I assume you have already done `pip install python-nmap`

Comment: ***choco install python***, ***choco install nmap*** and ***pip install python-nmap***

Answer (score 0):

Faced similar issue while trying to run `nm= nmap.PortScanner()`

I tried most of the solutions given above, but they did not work for me. The thing that worked for me was installing nmap for Mac OS X using home brew (Information at: http://brew.sh) and running the command

```
$ brew install nmap.
```

Now `nm= nmap.PortScanner()` runs without the earlier error.

Answer (score 0):

Running on Raspberry Pi 3 with Jessy lite

I had to:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade
```

then I could:

```
sudo apt-get install nmap

nmap --version
```

Answer (score 0):

Note about nmap

I used nmap to search the mask 192.168.1.0/24, but it didnt seam to find ALL ip´s. Eg: my laptop on 192.168.1.119 wasnt found, so I ended up using a combination of:

```
def ping(self, ip):
    # Use the system ping command with count of 1 and wait time of 1.
    ret = subprocess.call(['ping', '-c', '1', '-W', '1', ip],
                          stdout=open('/dev/null', 'w'),
                          stderr=open('/dev/null', 'w'))

    return ret == 0 # Return True if our ping command succeeds
```

inside a multithreaded Pinger

Pinger I got from: http://blog.boa.nu/2012/10/python-threading-example-creating-pingerpy.html

I created my own IpInfo class to store information and search for open ports on each IP, and here I use nmap: (Code is "work in progress", but you will get the idea. Ideas to tune performance would be nice)

```
class IpInfo(object):
ip = None
hostname = None
ports = []
lastSeenAt = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())


def findHostName(self):
    if(ip):
        self.hostname = str(socket.gethostbyaddr(ip)[0])
    else:
        raise NameError('IP missing')

def findOpenPorts(self):
    print('findOpenPorts')
    nm = nmap.PortScanner()
    nm.scan(host)
    nm.command_line()
    nm.scaninfo()

    for proto in nm[self.ip].all_protocols():
        print('----------')
        print('Protocol : %s' % proto)

        lport = nm[self.ip][proto].keys()   #<------ This 'proto' was changed from the [proto] to the ['tcp'].
        lport.sort()

        for port in lport:
            if(nm[self.ip][proto][port]['state'] == 'open'):
                self.ports.append(port)
```

Answer (score 0):

for macOS user simply use `brew install nmap` instead of using pip

Answer (score 0):

I have a perfect solution for this..

**First type**:- `apt-get remove nmap`

**Then** :- `apt autoremove`

**Then** :- go to  `www.pypi.org`

*And* type python nmap and download the **0.6** version

Extract it using command :- `tar -zxvf filename`

**cd** to the new extracted file

Type:- `python setup.py install`

And then

`apt-get install nmap`

***And you are ready to go.***

Comment: Why are you advocating dowloading from PyPi over using pip?

Comment: Actually when i did  a pip install ..then i got the same issue .... but then i tried a manual install from pypi and it worked ...most importantly ...if pip is causing an error ....then why not install from PyPi as pip also gets the package from PyPi repository. IT WORKED FOR ME!

Comment: I think it is more important to take the Versio 6.0 instead of doing without pip install. You can also specify the version in pip accordingly.