# nmap PortScannerError, can't find nmap

Tags: python, nmap

Not sure what I'm missing. I'm trying to import the nmap module and use the nmap.PortScanner(). I am using Linux. When I go to run the program in the terminal I get:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nmap/nmap.py", line 137, in __init__
raise PortScannerError('nmap program was not found in path')
nmap.nmap.PortScannerError: 'nmap program was not found in path'
```

When I run:

```
which nmap
```

I get:

```
/usr/bin/nmap
```

When I execute

```
nmap --version
```

I get:

```
Nmap version 7.60 ( https://nmap.org )
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Compiled with: liblua-5.3.3 openssl-1.1.0g nmap-libssh2-1.8.0 libz-1.2.8 libpcre-8.39 libpcap-1.8.1 nmap-libdnet-1.12 ipv6
Compiled without:
Available nsock engines: epoll poll select
```

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15335753/nmap-not-found-class-nmap-nmap-portscannererror

Comment: I tried following that question and response but the result of nmap --version is relatively the same, which would suggest nmap is installed and in the $PATH right?

Comment: Yes, I just added it for other people browsing the question and thinking of answering. Your question is different than that question.

Answer (score 0):

you need to edit the line 137 in "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nmap/nmap.py"
then include your nmap directory : "usr/bin/nmap".

this error is because of the "nmap.py" cant determine the nmap binary directory.

good luck

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for answering the old question but had faced the same issue and resolved it by changing the `nmap_search_path` in `nmap.py` file.

In nmap.py, the `__init__` function initializes PortScanner module and it has some default search paths to detect the `nmap` on the system and `nmap` version. It may raise `PortScannerError` exception if `nmap` is not found in the path.

For the `python-nmap-0.6.1` version which I checked has the below line of code in `nmap.py` file.

`def __init__(self, nmap_search_path=('nmap', '/usr/bin/nmap', '/usr/local/bin/nmap', '/sw/bin/nmap', '/opt/local/bin/nmap')):`