# why is my Nmap module not working in python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, nmap

I am currently learning ethical hacking with python and am trying to use Nmap however after installing it, and doing some simple scripting I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nmap_test.py", line 3, in <module>
    nmap1 = nmap.PortScanner()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nmap/nmap.py", line 131, in __init__
    os.getenv('PATH')
nmap.nmap.PortScannerError: 'nmap program was not found in path. PATH is : /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin'
```

Previous to this I got a different error saying the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nmap_test.py", line 3, in <module>
    nmap1 = nmap.PortScanner()
AttributeError: module 'nmap' has no attribute 'PortScanner'
```

With the bottom error I had installed just 'nmap' using pip3 (as I am using python3.7) and when that did not work I uninstalled 'nmap' and installed 'python-nmap' but then I got the top error message.

Please can someone help me out, I would greatly appreciate it. I have included my code below just for reference.

```
import nmap

nmap1 = nmap.PortScanner()

a = nmap1.nmap_version()

print(a)
```

Comment: python-nmap is definitely the package you want.  The other nmap is a numerical package that doesn't appear to be maintained.  The problem you're running into in that the nmap python module requires the nmap binary to be installed on your system and to be in a known location or on the path.  In this case, it's not finding the nmap binary on the path.  It looks like you're on macOS.  The easiest way to get the nmap binary is to install it via homebrew: `brew install nmap` (if you have homebrew set up)

Comment: This first answer in the following might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15335753/nmap-not-found-class-nmap-nmap-portscannererror

Comment: @JohnSzakmeister do you have a link to how to set up homebrew please, thanks for the help so far

Comment: Check out the Homebrew website: https://brew.sh/  It has all the details you need. :-)

Comment: I have now installed nmap with brew but I still get Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nmap_test.py", line 3, in <module>
    nmap1 = nmap.PortScanner()
AttributeError: module 'nmap' has no attribute 'PortScanner'

Comment: never mind it works now thanks a lot!!

Comment: You're welcome!  Glad you got it working.

Comment: All possible issues with `nmap` have been described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71652574/getting-error-attributeerror-module-nmap-has-no-attribute-portscanner/71660197) in details. Thx

Answer (score 1):

Nmap is a tool used for Networking Scanning.
First install nmap dependencies using the command

```
pip install python-nmap
```

If you want to use the nmap tool directly in debian.

```
sudo apt install nmap
```

This will work for you more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

The top error message,

> nmap program was not found

is because the nmap application does not exist, even though the `nmap.py` module exists. To fix it you have to install the nmap application:

> $ brew install nmap

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of nmpas

uninstall nmap

```
pip uninstall nmap
```

then install

```
pip install python-nmap
```

still use import nmap though