# python-nmap: nmap.PortScanner() - path error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, python-3.7

So as I imported python-nmap library to my interpreter:

```
import nmap
nm = nmap.PortScanner()
```

nmap.PortScanner() somehow shows me the following error. The installed python-nmap is 0.6.1 version, but the following error shows

> File "
>   ...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\nmap\nmap.py",
>   line 131, in **init**
>       os.getenv('PATH')

I'm working with python v3.7 although I installed nmap package + python-nmap.

> File "...\networkScanner.py", line 78, in 
>       nmapScanner(subnets, csvfolder)   File "...\networkScanner.py", line 21, in nmapScanner
>       nm = nmap.PortScanner()  # instantiate nmap.PortScanner object

Answer (score 2):

**For Windows users:**

First: closing all terminals and IDLE or any other window you currently have opened when trying to run your script.

Next, open a command line and type
`pip uninstall python-nmap`

Next, make sure that you installed nmap by typing 
`nmap`

If it is installed, continue to the next step, if not, go to [Nmap's official download page](https://nmap.org/download.html)

After installation, Open your system's environment variables editor usually found in

`My PC > System Information > Advance settings > Environment Variables`

select `Path` for both You and the System

press `Edit` and enter the full path to your Nmap director

eg `;C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap\`
Press ok and exit the editor.

Now go back to your command line and enter: 
`pip install python-nmap`
Allow it to install and then restart your ide and test your code again.

Reference [('Nmap not found', )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15335753/nmap-not-found-class-nmap-nmap-portscannererror)